# Como preservar Log da Consola do navegador Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, firefox, log, console

No navegador Google Chrome, na aba `consola`, existe uma opção para `preservar log` enquanto estamos a testar coisas ou a desenvolver o nosso site para que não tenhamos que voltar a escrever o código todo de novo caso tenhamos de atualizar a página para testar alguma coisa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Mozilla Firefox, existe alguma opção como esta para `preservar log`? Eu estive à procura e não encontrei nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No console de desenvolvimento, há uma opção `Toolbox Options`:

[image: Toolbox Options]

Ao clicar nessa opção, na tela `Common Preferences`, você pode escolher `Enable persistent logs`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>testado com FireFox 44.0.2 (64-bit)</sub>

Comment: Obrigado Gomiero, era mesmo isto que precisava :)